# Read data from Json and store in variable javascript

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am getting a response of an api request in JSON format which I store in a variable with json data like this structure

```
const users=    {
    'ABC': {
        id: '123',
        name:'testname',
    },
    'DEF': {
        id = '222',
        name='testname2'
    }
}
```

I am trying to read each data under users and store in a different variable. One variable lets say name firstVar which will have all date under 'ABC' and secondVar which will have all data under'DEF' which i can then use for further tests. I am not sure how to achieve it. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: It's probably supposed to be something like `users.find(item => item.id === "123")` instead of what you have

Comment: I already tried this and it kept giving me error , undefined

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the ids of each object and store them you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and return an array of ids.

```js
const users = {
  'ABC': {
      id: '123'
  },
  'DEF': {
      id: '222'
  }
};

const ids = Object.values(users).map(el => {
  return el.id;
});

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, your code is cut off. Array.prototype.find function only works for Array.

```
const users = {
    'ABC': {
        id: '123'
    },
    'DEF': {
        id: '222'
    }
};

const foundId = Object.keys(users).find(username => users[username].id === '123');

users[foundId] // found user.
```

Comment: You code returns `ABC`. The OP is looking to get the values from the `id` property in each object.

Comment: I see what you mean there, but this saves the OP time by skipping the extra step of storing the ids to an array unless that is relevant.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little confusing. The text of the question suggests the OP needs the ids, but the OP's attempt at the code suggests otherwise. It maybe that they're not really understanding how `find` works. My answer addresses the "getting all the ids" issue but, ultimately, I may be wrong :)